Removing final Exchange server - confused about how to run some of the commands
Following the guide here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/manage-hybrid-exchange-recipients-with-management-tools
I'm at step 5 under Permanently Shutting Down Your Last Exchange Server. That step says the following:
List of Commands
Are these commands in each block run one at a time? Do they provide output that needs to be copied and entered later? The instructions on this part are not very clear.
ie. Do I type:
$thumbprint = (Get-AuthConfig).CurrentCertificateThumbprint
Then hit Enter? The type:
$oAuthCert = (dir Cert:\LocalMachine\My) | where {$_.Thumbprint -match $thumbprint}
Then hit Enter? Etc?
Do I look for output to enter in another command later? I can usually parse these commands and they are usually clear about what values to note and when to enter the retrieved values as part of a command later, but in this case, it's not clear at all to me.

Yes, the commands provided in the guide are typically meant to be run one at a time, and some of them will generate output that you may need to use in subsequent commands. The sequence you provided looks correct, and I'll break down the steps for clarity.
Step-by-Step Execution:

Run the first command:
$thumbprint = (Get-AuthConfig).CurrentCertificateThumbprint

This command retrieves the thumbprint of the current authentication certificate and stores it in the $thumbprint variable.
There is no output to copy from this command directly since it stores the thumbprint in a variable.


Run the second command:
$oAuthCert = (dir Cert:\LocalMachine\My) | where {$_.Thumbprint -match $thumbprint}

This command searches the certificate store for the certificate that matches the thumbprint retrieved in the first command and stores that certificate in the $oAuthCert variable.
Again, there is no output to copy as it is stored in a variable.


Run the next command, and so on:
Set-AuthConfig -NewCertificateThumbprint $thumbprint

This command sets the new authentication certificate thumbprint.
No output to copy; it executes with the thumbprint already set in $thumbprint.





Do I type:
$thumbprint = (Get-AuthConfig).CurrentCertificateThumbprint
Then hit Enter? The type:
$oAuthCert = (dir Cert:\LocalMachine\My) | where {$_.Thumbprint -match
$thumbprint}
Then hit Enter? Etc?

Yes, exactly so.
In this case, the first command invokes Get-AuthConfig to retrieve a thumbprint for the certificate, and stores it in the local variable $thumbprint. It then looks through the certificate store for a certificate that matches $thumbprint  and stores the resulting certificate in the local variable $oAuthCert. So what you're doing is running a sequence of commands which generate output which gets stored, and is then used as unput to later commands.
